# Error on X having Y(X) greater equal to some constant A

Tags: error, error-propagation

There is a variable $Y(X)$ as a monotone increasing function of $X$, and there is an error data of $Y$.

I want to find the minimum $X$, satisfying $Y(X)\geq A$.

What will be the error on $X$ in this case?

Here $Y(X)$ is not given analytically but some data points on $X$ exist.

To be specific, for the case in the image, where the errorbar on $Y$ is $1~\sigma$ range for example, will the minimum $X$ be $X_{center}$ and the error be $X_{center}-X_{min}$ and $X_{max}-X_{center}$ with the confidence of $1~\sigma$?

[image]

Comment: The answer depends (very much) on how those error bars are calculated: are they independent or not?  What is assumed about the properties of this function and how is it estimated?